# In memoriam Torsten Ekedahl

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

This is not a question, just very, very, very sad news. Our community has lost one of its most active members. I am posting a letter I received recently.

From Carel Faber and Sandra Di Rocco:

November 23, 2011

Dear colleagues from the Algebraic Geometry community,

Unfortunately, we have some very sad news:

Torsten Ekedahl has passed away.

Torsten collapsed this morning at the Stockholm University Mathematics Department and died shortly thereafter. Attempts of colleagues and ambulance personnel to resuscitate him were 
unfortunately unsuccessful.

The SU Mathematics Department and the mathematical communities in Stockholm and Sweden have suffered a great loss. All who knew Torsten personally or through his work know that he was an exceptional mathematician, in many different ways. Torsten's main interest was Algebraic Geometry, but his research and knowledge went far beyond our field.

Torsten Ekedahl will be sorely missed by many.

Carel Faber and Sandra Di Rocco

Comment: Surely this should be community wiki... Also, because it's not a question, I'm voting to close. Torsten Ekedahl will be sorely missed- may his memory be a blessing.

Comment: There is a thread on this very sad news on meta http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussion/1218/sad-news-about-torsten-ekedahl/ 

Still, since not everybody reads meta, under these special circumstances I think  making an exception to the rule no meta content on main is very justified.


Comment: Yes indeed, not everybody reads meta, and that includes the site's search function; I of course did a simple search to see whether someone had already posted this, and it didn't find the meta thread.

Comment: I think MathOverflow is not a good place for an online memorial.  If one is set up, however, I ask that a link to it be placed here and in the meta thread.  Indeed, if I or some other member of MathOverflow is told about the URL, we can arrange to link to it from this post and the meta thread as well.  Condolences.  Gerhard Paseman, 2011.11.24

Comment: Perhaps this could become a real question by dint of an edit requesting suitable experts to write a few lines describing Torsten Ekedahl's research achievements in a form, and with permissions, that could serve as a basis for an English-language Wikipedia article.
(There exists already a brief Swedish-language article, but lacking any mathematical content.)

Comment: Whether the right place or not, in my opinion, Balazs was absolutely right to post this very sad news here in the forum, where Torsten has made so great contributions. 

Comment: The best way to deal with a loss like this is to rather celebrate the life, the person, and the math that connects him to countless strangers. But despite that, I still feel a strong recurrent hesitation to use MO an online memorial---less for the sake of MO, more out of respect, and for the modesty of silence that death occasions us to display.